# Grails. STS. Syntax highlighting problem?

Tags: grails, ide, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I create `Grails` project use `STS IDE`.
And sometimes i see not correct Syntax highlighting. and this "sometimes" - very often.

Some body have this problem too? or only I?

Comment: With such - possibly - Bug-related questions, you need to include detailed information on your system, including versions, etc. - Also look at the Eclipse log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax highlighting problems have been fixed since STS 2.5.3.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend IntelliJ, it's the best IDE for Grails development. They have community edition and professional edition.